# Execute javascript and return response (JavaFX/Swing)

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview, webengine

I need to run a javascript function from java and save the response in a variable. I wrote the following code but it does not work:

```
public Object execute(String value) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        new JFXPanel();
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            WebView browser = new WebView();
            WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
            webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            Object response = webEngine.executeScript(value);
            Platform.exit();
        });
    });
    return response;
}
```

I'm using "WebView" because my javascript code, uses functions like "window", "document" and the libraries as "ScriptEngineManage" does not work in my case.

How can i solve this problem? My code works but the "response" is returned before that the `executeScript` ends.

Comment: How do you determine that you get the result before the script is finished? It would also help to see the content of `value` which is the script that is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You never set any content to your WebView. You need to call something like

```
browser.getEngine().load(url)
```

or

```
browser.getEngine().loadContent(html)
```

You need to provide at least a minimal html page to be able to access JS objects like *window* or *document*. And you have to wait for the WebEngine's state to have finished the load before accessing the Javascript objects.